# GitLab setting up an ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I clone an empty project directory from a project I'm part of, after configuring git global as:

```
$ git config --global user.name "My Username"
$ git config --global user.email "myeamil.com"

$ git clone git@gitlab.com:our-projects/this-project.git
$ cd this-project
$ touch README.md
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "add README"
```

Then a follow the steps described [here](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair) to generate and add an `ssh key` (I actually created an `ED25519 SSH keys`). But testing to ensure the ssh was correctly added failed.

```
$ ssh -T git@our-projects/this-project.git
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:it-porto/transportation-mode-detection.git: Name or service not known

$ ssh -T git@our-projects
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:it-porto/transportation-mode-detection.git: Name or service not known

$ ssh -T git@this-project.git
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:it-porto/transportation-mode-detection.git: Name or service not known
```

Content of my ssh key directory:

```
$ ls /home/user/.ssh/
id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  known_hosts.old
```

How do I fix this?

**EDIT**

I did a `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` as suggested in the comment, a welcome message displayed, but this doesn't seem to work, I cannot `git push` to the remote.

```
$ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GitLab, @user!

$git push origin master
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 45.49 KiB | 3.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: 
remote: A default branch (e.g. master) does not yet exist for our-projects/this-project
remote: Ask a project Owner or Maintainer to create a default branch:
remote: 
remote:   https://gitlab.com/our-projects/this-project/-/project_members
remote: 
To gitlab.com:our-project/tthis-project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:our-projects/this-project.git'


$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.com:our-projects/this-projectt.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:our-projects/this-projectt.git (push)
```

Comment: You need the *host name* in the ssh-command, not the repository name: `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Comment: Ah, ok. they said gitlab.com should be replaced by instance name "To test whether your SSH key was added correctly, run the following command in
your terminal (replacing gitlab.com with your GitLab's instance domain):"  `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Comment: That "instance name" applies when you run your own copy of the gitlab software under a different domain name.

Comment: OK. I did as you said, with welcome message, but can't push to remote as per my question edit.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimSauer this messed me up for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You are good to go

```
Read the content of file by  cat id_rsa.pub
```

And copy the content from terminal
open your gitlab UI
from the top left click on user and then setting.

goto ssh and  paste your above content in box
[image]

Comment: Sure I did. I created an ED25519 SSH keys, instaed. Though the process is the same.